# Code Igniter Query Binding

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have the following query to select rows from a table based on rownumber.

```
$targeted_rows = implode(",",$wanted);


$sql =  "SELECT * FROM (
     SELECT @row:=@row+1 as rownum, productsa.* FROM (
     SELECT @row:=0
            )r,productsa
            )ranked
            WHERE rownum IN (?)  ";
$q = $this->db->query($sql, $targeted_rows);

if($q->num_rows() > 0) {
    foreach ($q->result() as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
return $data;
};
```

Currently my query is being executed like this. With the quotes around numbers and it is not working.

```
SELECT * FROM (
               SELECT @row:=@row+1 as rownum, productsa.* FROM (
                  SELECT @row:=0
               )r,productsa
            )ranked
            WHERE rownum IN ('1,4,7,10,13,16,19,22,25,28,31,34,37,40,43,46,49,52,55,58,61,64,67,70,73,76,79,82,85,88,91,94,97,100,103,106,109,112,115,118,121,124,127,130,133,136,139,142,145,148,151,154,157,160,163,166,169,172')
```

But when I manually execute the query without the quotes it works fine. I am at a completely loss on how to do the binding without the quotes showing up in the query.

edit: I've tried removing the implode and using the below code but I get the same problem

```
foreach ($wanted as $value){ 
  $targeted_rows .= $value . ","; 
}    
$this->db->escape($targeted_rows);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps simply make it safer with $this->db->escape as Sudhir mentioned previously, and then simply inject the escaped values into the SQL (without Query Binding)?

```
$escaped_wanted = array();
foreach ($wanted as $id) {
  $escaped_wanted[] = $this->db->escape($id);
}
$targeted_rows = implode(",", $escaped_wanted);
$sql =  "SELECT * FROM (
     SELECT @row:=@row+1 as rownum, productsa.* FROM (
     SELECT @row:=0
            )r,productsa
            )ranked
            WHERE rownum IN ({$targeted_rows})";
$q = $this->db->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way it will work is instead of using implode, contatenate the ids using foreach loop, then use:

```
$this->db->escape();  //to make it safer
```

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm missing but when i try it as
 <pre>   foreach ($wanted as $value){
  $targeted_rows .= $value . ",";
 } 
  $this->db->escape($targeted_rows);
</pre>
I get the same query output with quote marks (I have no idea how to format code in comments.)